# First chapter appearing before first line in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, include

I have a table of contents in my `memoir` book. I want there to be one line for each chapter, in addition to headings for each set of similar chapters.

For some reason, the line for the first chapter appears before the first `phantom` line.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 1}

\include{intro}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

This is the second chapter.

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

This is the third chapter.

\chapter{Chapter 4}

This is the fourth chapter.

\end{document}
```

The file `intro.tex` in the same directory contains the following:

```
\chapter{Introduction} \label{chap:intro}

\noindent This is the introductory chapter.
```

I've noticed that if I paste the contents of `intro.tex` into the main file (instead of using `\include`), the problem is fixed--the "Introduction" line in the table of contents appears before "Topic 1"!  However, this isn't a good solution, since I have large chapter files which I want to include separately...

What might be causing this problem?  And is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Gonzalo's solution works, but I'm still wondering if there might be something more elegant (which doesn't require changing anything in the `\include`d files)?

Comment: As I said, it's a well known problem and the "standard solution" is the one I mentioned in my answer. I can give you one or two possible alternatives, but I am not sure they will be "more elegant"; anyway, the change to be done is only adding two lines, so I don't see any big problem.

Comment: I've now updated my answer with an explanation of the cause of the problem and a description of several possible solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a well known problem with `\addcontentsline` (or `\addtocontents`) and `\include`; simply move the lines

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 1}
```

to the file `intro.tex`.

Let's take a look at the cause of the problem; for simplicity's sake let us consider the following sample file `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 1}
\include{intro}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

and file intro.tex is something like

```
\chapter{Introduction}

Text
```

Of course, in a real document "Chapter 2" should also be written in its own `.tex` file and `\includ`ed in `main.tex`, but this is not relevant for the explanation below.

Two things are important here:

1. Each `\includ`ed file produces its own `.aux` file.
2. The information about the table of contents is not written directly to the `.toc` file; the `\@write`s go first to the `.aux` file(s) and only at the execution of `\enddocument` this information is read form the `.aux` file(s) and written to the `.toc` file.

Now, let's follow some of the steps of the processing of `main.tex`. Just before the `\end{document}` is reached, the files `main.aux` and `main.toc` are still empty, but, and this is crucial, the file `intro.aux` has already been written and contains (amongst other things) the line.

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Introduction}{1}}
```

When `\enddocument` is being executed, file `main.aux` will be processed and will contain the lines

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {part}{Topic 1}{1}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10pt}}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10pt}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Chapter 2}{3}}
```

Also, the writes to the `.toc` file are done, but by the time this is done, the  order is not the expected (remember that `intro.aux` was written first): the write associated to "Introduction" will be done first, then the one for "Topic 1" and finally the one for "Chapter2".  In fact, the file `main.toc` will be

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Introduction}{1}
\contentsline {part}{Topic 1}{1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Chapter 2}{3}
```

The nex processing of the document will find the lines in that order and the lines will be typeset in the document in the wrong order.

### Possible Solutions

1. Move the `\addtocontents` line to the beginning of `intro.tex`. Doing this, when `intro.aux` is written it contains the lines

   ```
   \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {part}{Topic 1}{1}}
   \@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10pt}}
   \@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10pt}}
   \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Introduction}{1}}
   ```

   so now the `\@write`s to the `.toc` file will be in the right order:

   ```
   \contentsline {part}{Topic 1}{1}
   \contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Introduction}{1}
   \contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Chapter 2}{3}
   ```

   I understand that this might sound "hackish", but other alternative solutions (see below) are also more or less of the same nature.
2. If you don't need the `\includeonly` feature available for `\include`, you can use `\input` instead (notice however that `\input` doesn't issue `\cleardoublepage` or `\clearpage` internally). `\input` doesn't produce `.aux` files for the subsidiary documents and this will prevent the problem.
3. If you need to use `\include` and all your included files will take care of issuing `\cleardoublepage` or `\clearpage` when necessary (for example, if all the included files contain `\chapter`), then you can process your document as it is; this will produce the wrong order in the table of contents) but will let you profit from the `\includeonly` functionality and then, for the final version, replace all the `\include` commands for `\input` commands and perform a final complete processing (performing as many runs as the document requires).
4. Use a subsidiary file for the `\addtocontents` line and `\include` it in your main document. In the example, `main.tex` would look now like this:

   ```
   \mainmatter

   \include{topic1}
   \include{intro}
   \chapter{Chapter 2}
   ```

   with `topic1.tex` containing the line

   ```
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 1}
   ```