# \chaptername is used even for appendix chapters in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices, tocloft, naming

I have searched for something to resolve a problem that has shown up here:
[How do I get \chaptername to appear in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/how-do-i-get-chaptername-to-appear-in-the-table-of-contents)

I have tried the code from that thread. But I got an issue, that is, it adds the `\chaptername` even for appendix chapters:

> Chapter 1. aaaaa
>   ....
>   Chapter Appendix A

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the start of the appendix, a redefinition of `\cftchappresnum` must be forwarded to the `.toc` file. I have appended the definition of `\appendix` to do so.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix~999~}}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{500}
\chapter{Hello}
\appendix
\chapter{Hello again}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply!
I dont know why, but it's seem that the problem is not complete resolved yet. It doesn't make effect on the first appendix chapter. And the result is:
> Chapter A Appendix tittle.
> Appendix B Appendix tittle.

Comment: @xuansamdinh Thanks for accepting my answer, but please also upvote it (this has to be done separately from accepting).

Comment: Oh, it's suprise that it's doesn't effect to the first chapter when use `\include` to include appendix chapters, such as `\include{appendA}`. But when put these chapters directly to the main file or using the `\input` command, it's work nice!
Could you improve the code for more nice working?
Thank you!

Comment: @xuansamdinh Try to add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}}` at the start of your first "included" appendix chapter file. I suspect that it's a problem similar to the one solved in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50037/510.