# Table of Contents with Chapter and Appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices, tocloft, naming

I'm using this code to get word Chapter in TOC before each chapter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapter }}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\include{Intro}


\cleardoublepage
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\include{Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

This code also adds Chapter word before appendix. I wonder how to get word Appendix before the appendix in TOC.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56839/chaptername-is-used-even-for-appendix-chapters-in-toc

Comment: Notice that you use files `Appendix.tex` and `Intro.tex` and you do not post them. You should have made your code simpler if you just made examples of a `\chapter` before and inside the `appendices` environment, without the need of extra files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do the changes while reading the `.toc` file: this is an example of how to do it. The double `\unexpanded` is because the `toc` entry is first written in the `.aux` file and then in the `.toc`, so we have to protect it twice. One could add several `\protect`, but this is surely easier to write.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}

\newcommand{\setupname}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{%
      \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{#1 }%
      \setlength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries #1 }}%
      \addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\fixedchapnumwidth}%
    }}%
  }%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\fixedchapnumwidth{\the\cftchapnumwidth}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\setupname{Chapter}
\chapter{Title}

text

\chapter{Another}

text

\appendix
\setupname{Appendix}
\chapter{Title}

text

\end{document}
```

The `\setupname` command might be integrated in `\mainmatter` and in `\appendix`, but this is left as an exercise. :)

Comment: It must be added that `\setupname` must be added to the included file if `\include` is used, otherwise it will only be inserted after the included file. It is therefor doubtfull if you can make a foolproof integration with `\mainmatter` and `\appendix` because a `shipout` is needed before the `\addtocontents` is written to the AUX file.

Comment: @DanieEls I *never* use `\include`, but you're right. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Add this line after `\begin{appendices}`:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftchappresnum{\appendixname{} }}
```

It adds a line to the TOC file that changes the title of the chapters (you ought to run twice).
You might as well want to change the label width, so put `Appendix` instead of `Chapter` in the `\AtBeginDocument...` line.

Answer (score 1):

The answers using `tocloft` works fine if you are not using the `\include` command. The problem is the delayed write mechanism used inside the `\addtocontents` to put stuff in the toc usualy ends up after the include contents. Solutions that works under all conditions are:

(1) It is the default behaviour of the `amsbook` class

(2)  With `memoir` it can be obtain by putting the following in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{PART~}
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{\appendixname~}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}% dot after the number
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2em}
```

(3) With the standard `book` class you need a lot of changes. The following is from [c.t.t.](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/9e4763ac3eb1dee0) and was the basis of the code that ended up in `memoir`

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
%% Add a conditional to \appendix. Could also use \@chapp.
\newif\if@inappendix\@inappendixfalse
\let\oldappendix=\appendix
\renewcommand*{\appendix}{\oldappendix\@inappendixtrue}

%% User defined number width in TOC (\tocchpnumwdth)
%% Add inserts for Chapter and Appendix. Define to
%% \relax if standard output is needed.
\newlength{\tocchpnumwdth}
\setlength{\tocchpnumwdth}{1.5em}
\newcommand*{\tocchapinsert}{\chaptername\space}
\newcommand*{\tocappinsert}{\appendixname\space}

%% Small change in \@chapter. Write write different contents
%% line for Chapter and Appendix. Add inerts to \numberline.
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \if@mainmatter
          \refstepcounter{chapter}%
          \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
          \if@inappendix
             \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}%<-- THIS IS NEW
               {\protect\numberline{\tocappinsert\thechapter}#1}%<-
          \else
             \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
               {\protect\numberline{\tocchapinsert\thechapter}#1}%<-
          \fi
       \else
          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
       \fi
    \else
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn
       \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
    \else
       \@makechapterhead{#2}%
       \@afterheading
    \fi}

%% Creates a \l@appendix identical to \l@chapter. Add the
%% width of the inserts to the width of the \numberline
%% box (\@tempdima).
\renewcommand*\l@chapter{\l@@chapter{\tocchapinsert}}
\newcommand*\l@appendix{\l@@chapter{\tocappinsert}}%<-- NEW

\newcommand*\l@@chapter[3]{%
   \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
     \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
     \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
     \begingroup
       \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
       \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
       \leavevmode \bfseries
       \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#1}%           <- change
       \addtolength\@tempdima{\tocchpnumwdth}%<- change
       \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
       \hskip -\leftskip
       #2\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #3}\par
       \penalty\@highpenalty
     \endgroup
   \fi}

%% Keep hyperref happy
\def\toclevel@appendix{0}

\makeatother
\usepackage[breaklinks=true, % for long names
           ]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    \chapter{Preface}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Nomenclature}
\mainmatter
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \section{First Section}
\appendix
    \chapter{First Appendix}
    \section{First Appendix Section}
\backmatter
    \chapter{Data Tables}
\end{document}
```