# Using different \cftsetindents for Appendix entries in Table of Contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, formatting, appendices, tocloft

Related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59349/table-of-contents-with-chapter-and-appendix) question, which specified how to relabel the Chapter prefix for appendices. But now my spacing is off because it's still using the same indent. Can I do something similar to `\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftchappresnum{}}` but to redefine the `\cftsetindents` for the Appendix chapters in the TOC?

MWE: (note the large horizontal whitespace between "Appendix A1." and "Example")

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft} % customize TOC font/spacing
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter } % prefix "Chapter " to chapter number in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}    % add period after chapter number
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{7em}      % set amount of indenting for chapter in TOC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\arabic{chapter}} % Appendix A#
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftchappresnum{}} % Appendix A1 instead of Chapter Appendix A1 in TOC
\chapter{Example}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The tocloft manual specifies that the command `\cftsetindents{entry}{indent}{numwidth}` sets the entry’s indent and its numwidth. In my case, I needed to modify the numwidth. The following command worked for me (I put it right after the `\begin{appendices}` line):

`\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5em}}`

Comment: Finally found the answer which solves my problem. Thank you!