# Add chapter/appendix prefix in table of contents of scrbook with correct appendix running head 

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, appendices, scrbook

My first question is how to add the chapter or appendix prefix in the table of contents of scrbook class instead of the its default appearance.

For example, in the figure below, I want to change the chapter entry in TOC to Chapter 1. Introduction.
[image]

and the same goes for the appendix entry in TOC, which means typesetting Appendix A. Electro... instead of the figure below.

[image]

Additionally, I have used **`\appendix`** before starting my appendices, so it treats all the subsequent chapters as chapters A, B, etc. However, I want to treat them as appendices to appear correctly in the page headings as "Appendix A. Electro..." instead of "Chapter A. Electro..." in the page heading as shown below.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first question can be solved by using the `tocstyle`-package included in the KOMAscript-bundle. Try

```
 texdoc tocstyle
```

at an command prompt to see the documentation.

By redefining some internal variables, if I understand your question correctly, you will have the answer to your first question. Put this commands in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{\chapapp\nobreakspace #1}{#2}%
}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
```

Your second question was:

> However, I want to treat them as appendices to appear correctly in the page headings as "Appendix A. Electro..."

This be solved by using the class-option `chapterprefix=true` or `appendixprefix=true`, if I understand your question correctly.

A complete MWE, which (hopefully) solve all questions:

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{\chapapp\nobreakspace #1}{#2}%
}

\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\appendix

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

If you are using `\chapter` in `\fronmatter`, remember to use the starred version to avoid a `Chapter .` with empty number in your Table of Contents. Also, if you are using the command `\addchap`in you document, use the starred version (`\addchap*`}.

For further reading, see page 80 in the [English manual](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), and [this discussion](http://www.komascript.de/node/1418) at the [KOMAscript homepage](http://komascript.de).

**NB!** This code needs a recent version of `komascript`.

Comment: Thanks for help, but the MWE doesnt work and I got this "! LaTeX Error: \addchaptertocentry undefined."

Comment: Strange, The MWE works on my system (updated MikTeX on Win 7). What is your version of `koma-script`?

Comment: After updating the Miktex 2.9 packages, the same error appears. Regarding the Koma version, here is the line from log file: Document Class: scrbook 2010/09/17 v3.07 KOMA-Script document class (book

Comment: @Diaa Current version of `komascript` is 3.11a. My `scrbook` reports:  `scrbook 2012/05/15 v3.11 KOMA-Script document class (book)`. If your `miktex` that does not update your packages correctly, or maybe you have a copy of `scrbook` in your `texmf-local` (or whatever you have named your private TeX directory). The code need a recent version of `komascript`.

Comment: You have inspired me with the solution. First, I uninstalled the Koma bundle. Second, I deleted the directory "C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script". In case of compiling the file again, the bundle will be installed on the fly. Your help and patience are highly appreciated.

Comment: I have irrelevant question, how did you get this syntax of overwriting the built-in code of the package ? I know it may be trivial question but I am very beginner in latex and I am highly interested in learning these ways of editing.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I have referenced my sources in the last paragraph in the answer, Komascript’s manual page 80 and a tread at Komascript’s homepage. See the last paragraph in my answer and the links.

Comment: Thanks, but now after re-installing Miktex 2.9, I get the references entry in TOC as "Chapter. References" and I am using the  book option of "bibliography=totoc". Can you help me in removing this prefix of "Chapter" in case of bibliography ?

Comment: I fixed it by removing the option "bibliography=totoc" and inserting "\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}" after \bibliography{<bibfile.bib>}. If available, can you tell me why does this awkward entry appear in case of using the class option ?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou It because the reference is defined as a chapter heading. I am not familiar with bibliographies, but you solution seems correct. You can also try `\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{}` just after the `\bibliography{<bibfile>}`

Comment: Your solution can be valid, but it is not in my case unfortunately. Highly grateful for your time and help.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Are you using `bibtex` or `biblatex` to produce the bibliograpies?

Comment: Bibtex. I am sorry, but what the difference between them ?

Comment: If you use `\chapapp` instead `\chaptername` the command `\appendix` changes the prefix automatically. Note that if there is a `\chapter` in frontmatter or a `\addchap` command in the document you will get `Chapter .` in front of the unnumbered chapter toc entry. You have to control if the first argument of `\addchaptertocentry` is empty.

Comment: @esdd You are correct regarding the `\chapapp` instead of `\chaptername`. I have updated my MWE. Your second problem is solved by using the starred version of `\chapter` and `\addchap`, see page 92 ff. in KOMAscript’s user manual.

Comment: @Sveinung Insert `\addchap{test}` in your MWE, run three times and then have a look at the TOC ;-) There will be "Chapter . test" or "Appendix . test". Or use `\frontmatter` followed by a `\chapter` command. Or use `bibliography=totoc` as mentioned in a comment above. See page 358 ff. in the manual. Also option `listof=chapterentry` (see page 130) does not work with your code.

Comment: @esdd As I said: Use `\addchap*` and `\chapter*` instead of `\chapter` and `\addchap`. `bilbliography=totoc` and `listof=chapterentry` was not part of the original question. I think it is a good idea to put in a test for the first argument as you suggest.

Comment: Note: This answer is IMHO out-dated, because `tocstyle` is not longer part of the KOMA-Script bundle. It is declared as deprecated. BTW: The package was always declared to be experimental and never reached a non-experimental state.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the answer of the question [\chaptername is used even for appendix chapters in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56839/chaptername-is-used-even-for-appendix-chapters-in-toc)

the syntax of

```
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix~999~}}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

has a successful result in prefixing the chapters entries in TOC with the word "Chapter" (same for appendices).

For the running headings in the in the appendices environment, the following syntax changes

**Chapter** to **Appendix**

```
\begin{document}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Appendix\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\chapter{Appendix A}
\chapter{Appendix B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: You should not use `tocloft` with KOMA-Script class `scrbook`. See the warning message you'd get.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion that also works if you use chapters in frontmatter or options like `listof=totoc`, `listof=chapterentry` or if you use `\addchap`.

```
\documentclass[
  chapterprefix,
  %numbers=noenddot,
  %toc=indentunnumbered,
  listof=totoc,
  %listof=chapterentry
]{scrbook}[2016/05/10]

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}%
  }{%
    \ifstr{#1}{}
      {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}%<- unnumbered chapters in TOC
      {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{\chapapp{} #1}{#2}}%<- numbered chapters in TOC
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\chapter{This is a chapter in frontmatter}
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\begin{table}%
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  \Huge X
  \end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\addchap{This is an unnumbered chapter}
\addsec{This is an unnumbered section}
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]