# KOMA-script: Add word "Part" and "Chapter" in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

How can I add the word "Part" to the part entry and "Chapter" to chapter entries in the ToC?

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is a part}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129599/69174). But your question, maybe, is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add "Parts" to the Table of Contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129592/add-parts-to-the-table-of-contents)

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni I would prefer not to use any additional packages.

Comment: @close voter please this is koma-script not book class.

Comment: Already answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62388/9424. I see you don't want extra packages, but tocstyle is a koma-script bundle package.

Comment: @Joseph The linked answer does not work if there is an `\addchap` command in the document or an chapter in `\frontmatter`. It results in an `Chapter .` before such an unnumbered chapter entry in TOC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{\partname\nobreakspace #1}{#2}%
}%

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{\chaptername\nobreakspace #1}{#2}%
  \if@chaptertolists
    \doforeachtocfile{%
      \iftocfeature{\@currext}{chapteratlist}{%
        \addxcontentsline{\@currext}{chapteratlist}[{#1}]{#2}%
      }{}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{float@addtolists}{}{\scr@float@addtolists@warning}%
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is a part}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do not forget to run LaTeX at least three times when you are using the `tocindentauto` option from the `tocstyle` package (see p. 3 of the manual):

> With option `tocindentauto` all widths at the TOCs are calculated by
>   `tocstyle`. The calculation of the width needs at least one LaTeX run
>   with all TOC entries. So you need at least three LaTeX runs

Answer (score 5):

Here is another suggestion that still works if there is an unnumbered chapter or an unnumbered part or an appendix.

```
\documentclass[
  chapterprefix,
  %numbers=noenddot,
  %toc=indentunnumbered,
  %listof=totoc,
  %listof=chapterentry
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocnumwidth=4em
]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocnumwidth=6em
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocindent=6em
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocindent=8em
]{subsection}

\let\oldaddchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{%
    \oldaddchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}{%
    \oldaddchaptertocentry{\chapapp{} #1}{#2}%
}}
\let\oldaddparttocentry\addparttocentry
\renewcommand{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{%
    \oldaddparttocentry{#1}{#2}}{%
    \oldaddparttocentry{\partname{} #1}{#2}%
}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\chapter{This is a chapter in frontmatter}
\mainmatter
\part{This is a part}
\blinddocument
\begin{table}%
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  \Huge X
  \end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\addchap{This is an unnumbered chapter}
\addsec{This is an unnumbered section}
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Update** using KOMA-Script Version 3.20 (or newer)

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}[2016/05/10]

\newcommand\partentrynumberformat[1]{\partname\ #1}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat=\partentrynumberformat,
  tocnumwidth=4em
]{part}

\newcommand\chapterentrynumberformat[1]{\chapapp\ #1}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocentrynumberformat=\chapterentrynumberformat,
    tocnumwidth=5.5em
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=5.5em]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=7.8em]{subsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\chapter{This is a chapter in frontmatter}
\mainmatter
\part{This is a part}
\blinddocument
\begin{table}%
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  \Huge X
  \end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\addchap{This is an unnumbered chapter}
\addsec{This is an unnumbered section}
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\oldaddchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
\oldaddchaptertocentry{}{\@chapapp{} #1. #2}}
\let\oldaddparttocentry\addparttocentry
\renewcommand{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
\oldaddchaptertocentry{}{\partname{} #1. #2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is a part}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}

\part{This is a part}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\appendix

\part{This is a part}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Although I mentioned in the comment above that I would rather not use any additional packages I will accept Thorsten's answer which uses the tocstyle package. The reason for that comment was that I do not want to use packages which possibly interfere with the KOMA-script classes. Since the tocstyle package has been developed by the author of the KOMA-script classes there will not be any problems of compatibility but moreover this package offers me the possibility to easily change the appearance of the ToC without putting too much effort in searching the commands.

Answer (score 0):

(RUS) С учетом предложенных выше решений, я для себя нашёл ответ на данный вопрос. Он учитывает, что:

1. В русском языке слово "Приложение" намного больше слова "Глава", поэтому одинаковые отступы выглядят не красиво
2. Главы бывают ненумерованными
3. Мне не нравится слишком большой отступ перед section

(En) Taking into account the above solutions, I found the answer to this question for myself. He takes into account that:

1. In Russian, the word "Application" is much larger than the word "Chapter", so the same indentation does not look beautiful
2. Chapters are unnumbered 3.
3. I do not like too much indent before section

Добавьте следующий код в преамбулу (Add the following code to the preamble):

```
% Добавить слово Глава в оглавление
\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{% Глава без номера
    \originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}%
  }{% Глава с номером
    \originaladdchaptertocentry{}{\chapapp~#1. #2}%
  }%
}
```

[image: Пример (Sample)]

Answer (score 0):

Since is the package tocstyle is deprecated use tocbasic with:

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\chaptername},
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\partname},
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{part}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2\hfill}
```