# Appendices prefixed with "Chapter" instead of with "Appendix" in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

Everything works beautifully except that, in the TOC, the Appendices are prefixed by "Chapter" instead of by "Appendix" and I have no idea what controls these.

More precisely, I am getting:

`Chapter 1   Title`

`Chapter 2   Title`

`…`

`Chapter A   Title`

`Chapter B   Title`

where I would like

`Chapter 1   Title`

`Chapter 2   Title`

`…`

`Appendix A   Title`

`Appendix B   Title`

This is the [actual document](http://freemathtexts.org/InProgress/RAFv7.1/) but I have not been able to recreate this in a minimum working example and the best I got has no prefix whatsoever in the TOC:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red!50!black}}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
%\frontmatter

\Large \textsc{Reasonable Book}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}   
Some text \textbf{indexed}\index{indexed}   
\section{To begin with}
And then some more text.
%\noappendicestocpagenum%What does it do?

\appendixpage
\appendix
\chapter{This is text for the stuff that is needed.}    

\backmatter
\chapter{FDL}
The purpose of this License 

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}   
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to load `hyperef` as the last package (I cannot test it, because I cannot install packages on this computer).

Comment: @Sveinung The last four packages are: `appendix`, `makeidx`, `hyperref` and, after the Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' to call `showidx`, `cleveref`.  What is a pity is that, as mentioned above, the "actual document", which is rather intricate, otherwise works beautifully.

Comment: Well, when I run your MWE, I get neither `chapter` nor `appendix` as prefix in the table of contents, I just get `1` and `A`.

Comment: A classic mistake when using the package `appendix`: When using this package, you have to use the environment `\begin{appendices}... \end{appendices}`, not the command `\appendix`. On the other hand: The simplest way to archive your goal is to use the receipt in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56845/9632). Maybe you then have to skip the use of the `appendix`-package, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{apptools, etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect {CHAPTER }}{\ifappendix{APPENDIX }\else{CHAPTER }\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Even this "latex challenged" person could see that this was just what the doctor ordered but . . . I am afraid it didn't work here: neither in the MWE nor in the "actual document".