# Appendix font size too small in table of contents

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

I am trying to create my table of contents, but I want the text "Appendices" to have the same font size as a part (Investigation).  How can I increase the font size?  Also, I have tried `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}`, but that was entitled "Investigation Appendicies" (which...fail...), and I couldn't seem to change the `cftpartpresnum` at that point.  Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=4em]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}                  % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 

\usepackage{calc}

%% Rename "Part" to "Investigation" and append that label to the table of 
%% contents  
\renewcommand{\partname}{Investigation}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Investigation \Roman{part} --- Part}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}:}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Investigation }
\let\cftoldpartfont\cftpartfont
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\cftoldpartfont\cftpartpresnum}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{:}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Investigation \textrm{IV}:}}}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Part}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{ -- }
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Part B --}}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

%% Change formatting of the part so that things can be on the same page
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\partname\ \thepart}{0pt}{\huge}

\usepackage[toc,page,title]{appendix}


%% Remove headers from blank pages
\usepackage{emptypage}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{My maddness}
What can I say, I'm on a Tolkien kick.

\mainmatter
\part{The Hobbit}

\chapter{Bilbo Baggins}
\chapter{Thorin, Oin, Gloin, and the nine}
\chapter{The dragon under the mountain}

\part{The fellowship of the Ring}
\chapter{Frodo}
\chapter{Sam}
\chapter{Merry}
\chapter{Pippin}

\part{The two towers}
\chapter{Gandalf the White}
\chapter{Gimli}
\chapter{Legolas}

\part{Return of the King}
\chapter{Aragorn}
\chapter{Mount Doom}
\chapter{Who cares?}


\appendix

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Concerning Hobbits}
  \chapter{Maps}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, it would be good if the "Part" disappeared before the A and B in the appendix labels.  But one problem at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56839/chaptername-is-used-even-for-appendix-chapters-in-toc/56845#56845) and applied it here.

- I removed the appendix package
- I added the redefinition of the `\appendix` macro below

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\appendix{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
       \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{}%
       \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
       \protect\setlength{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix B --}}}
    }%
  }
  \makeatother
  ```

Then I just added this to the end:

```
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}
\chapter{Concerning Hobbits}
\chapter{Maps}

\end{document}
```