# How to rename chapters in Table Of Content in French document?

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, appendices

My document is in French. I added appendices to the document, appendices use \chapter{}, hence I would like that these chapters to be names "Annexe" (which is the French word for "Appendice" in table of content.

But I my current document I don't manage to do that.

I expect it has to do with the cutomization of my table of content. Which I want to keep as well.

working example:

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,french,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan
}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapitre }
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries Chapitre }}}


\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    
\part{main}
    \chapter{Lorem ipsum}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annexe}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexe}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexe}

\part{appendices}
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Some appendice}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \chapter{Some appendice}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

---

I know that this question has been closed and pointing to [\chaptername is used even for appendix chapters in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56839/chaptername-is-used-even-for-appendix-chapters-in-toc) but that didn't help me at all. Another answer is marked as solutions under this question. That one helped me solve the issue.

Comment: See the `babel` manual you need to add your name changes to the language it self somthing like `\addto\captionsfrench{.....}` where you supply the `...` part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\chaptername is used even for appendix chapters in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56839/chaptername-is-used-even-for-appendix-chapters-in-toc)

Comment: Your question has an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56839/118712 (BTW: The approach from daleif will not work with the `renewcommand` of `cftchappresnum`.)

Comment: Unrelated: It is generally advisable to load the `hyperref` package LAST, unless another package specificially and explicitly requires being loaded after `hyperref`.

Comment: Yet another question "closed" as "Already has an answer" ... then pointing to an answer that didn't help me solve the problem... I'm not sure how I should react...
I have already marked an answer as solution in this case anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak the `\addcontentsline` macro as it is done in the `appendix` package (when using the `titletoc` option).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}

% a command to tweak \addcontentsline for chapters
\newcommand{\chapitretocentry}{%
    \let\oldacl=\addcontentsline % save original definition
    \def\addcontentsline##1##2##3{% (re)define \addcontentsline
        \def\tempa{##1}\def\tempb{toc}% store ##1 and toc in temp vars
        \ifx\tempa\tempb % check if they are "equal"
            \def\tempa{##2}\def\tempb{chapter}%
            \ifx\tempa\tempb % check if ##2 is "equal" to chapter
                \oldacl{##1}{##2}{\chaptername\space ##3}% apply original \addcontentsline adding \chaptername
% in the other cases, just apply the original \addcontentsline
            \else
                \oldacl{##1}{##2}{##3}%
            \fi
        \else
            \oldacl{##1}{##2}{##3}%
        \fi
    }
}
\AtBeginDocument{\chapitretocentry} % invoke the command at the beginning

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan
}
\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \part{main}
    \chapter{Lorem ipsum}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    
    \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annexe}
    \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}
    \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexe}
    
    \part{Annexes}
    \let\addcontentsline=\oldacl % reset the original def
    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Some appendice}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \chapter{Some appendice}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{appendices}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like it works when I copy your whole answer, but I tried to "inject it" in my example and it didn't work... trying again...

Comment: Ok, got it working. Currently I'm half-lost in what it does but it works, thanks.

Comment: @TTT I added some comments to explain briefly the code

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell LaTeX that when processing the appendices in the TOC, `\chaptername` should become `\appendixname`.

The setting will disappear as soon as the TOC has been typeset, because this happens inside a group.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan
}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\ }
\AtBeginDocument{\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries\chaptername }}}
\AddToHook{env/appendices/begin}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\chaptername\string\appendixname}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
    
\part{main}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}

\lipsum[1-2]
    
\part{appendices}
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Some appendice}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Some appendice}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]