# Adding a line to the TOC before the appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, input, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [First chapter appearing before first line in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50036/first-chapter-appearing-before-first-line-in-table-of-contents)

I am having issues with inserting a line into the TOC when including external files. `\input` and `\include` behave differently in this case.

My MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{filecontents}{appen.tex}
\chapter{Appendix 1}
This is the appendix
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Main}
This is the main part.

\appendix
\part*{Appendix}                                                    
\addtocontents{toc}{%
\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Appendix}{}{}}

\input{appen}

\end{document}
```

works like a charm and does what I want it to. When I change the `\input` command into an `\include`, however, the note "Appendix" appears AFTER the chapter "Appendix 1".

I could just work with `\input`ing the first chapter of the appendix and `\include`ing the rest (which does work fine), but I wonder if anyone can explain this behaviour and maybe has a solution, so that I can `\include` the first appendix chapter, too.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think you are over complicating things, you shouldn't need to manually add to the TOC.

If you are insistent on using the `\begin{filecontents}` to simulate external files, I did notice that it doesn't overwrite if the file exists, this may be giving you  a false negative. Incidentally, the overwrite error is one of the reasons the `filecontents` package was developed, so try the below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{appen.tex}
    \chapter{An Appendix Chapter}
    This is the appendix
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Main}
This is the main part.

\appendix
\include{appen}
\end{document}
```